# Is this use of 'such as' correct?

Tags: legalese

> Later in 1991, the Court of Appeal dismissed all the claims on the ground that, apart from
>   rescuers, only parents and spouses could claim and that ‘a perception through the broadcast
>   of selective images accompanied by a commentary is not **such as** to satisfy the proximity
>   test’. Ten claimants then appealed unsuccessfully to the House of Lords.

I'm guessing that only [Definition 2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/180374/50720) of **such as** applies here, so replace with it:

> Later in 1991, the Court of Appeal dismissed all the claims on the ground that, apart from
>   rescuers, only parents and spouses could claim and that ‘a perception through the broadcast
>   of selective images accompanied by a commentary is not **Of a kind that** to satisfy the proximity
>   test’.

Now, this (eg "...that to satisfy") sounds grammatically wrong? Did I perceive **such as** correctly?

Source: P94, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Comment: *Such as* is fine here, it's more of legalese. The use of *such as* implies "... a commentary is not **one** to satisfy the proximity test (not **one** that **satisfies** / not of a kind that **satisfies** )."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of legalese, not English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at "such as" as if it were a two-word phrase that has (or should have) a particular meaning. It often is, but in this case it is not; "such" and "as" are independent actors on this stage, or, rather, semi-independent actors. An equivalent alternative reading would be

> [...] 'a perception through the broadcast of selective images accompanied by a commentary is not [a harmful consequence of] such [a kind] as to satisfy the proximity test.'

In this case, that part of the ruling was that merely seeing the aftermath of a tragedy on television or in the newspapers did not make the Chief Constable liable for the psychological harm suffered by the people who may have seen it, whatever liability he may have had for any of the other consequences of his actions; that harm was insufficiently proximate in time, place and relationship to the actual (physically injured or killed) victims. *Such*, in this case, embodies both of the additions I made above.